# ¿Por qué XAMPP no ejecuta mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

nunca habia fallado hasta hoy, pero suspongo que tambien puede ser porque tengo otros servidores locales para otros proyectos.
¿esto si podria afectar a XAMPP?
cabe mencionar que se supone que no deberian estar activos
Cualquier ayuda es recibida, gracias por leer
[image: Mysql se detiene]

Comment: Como dice el error es debido a que no puede utilizar el puerto. Revisa si otro programa utiliza el mismo puerto de MySQL.

Comment: Suele ocurrir esto cuando instalas algún nuevo programa que viene a ocupar el puerto que antes usaba `MySQL`. Revisa los puertos abiertos y quién los está usando. MySQL suele usar el puerto `3306`, verifica si es así y asegúrate de que nadie más lo use ... o cambia el puerto en MySQL.

Comment: Probablemente ya haya instalado y activo otro servidor MySQL anteriormente, si es asi debes desactivarlo o por lo menos detenerlo desde el administrador de servicios. Qué version de windows utilizas?

Comment: Utilizo windows 10, ¿como puedo checar si el puerto esta siendo usado?

Comment: Tu mismo lo dices. Tienes otros servidores activos. Si hiciete instalaciones ellas tratan de usar un puerto por defecto. Y, si al momento de instalarlas tu servidor xamp no estaba activo ellas han debido atrapar el puerto al que escucha la BD. Cuando los activas simultáneamente se pisan

Comment: Ha soluciones usando config de cada servicio y viendo el puerto al que escuchan. Tomas nota y luego verificas cuales pueden estar en conflicto, regresas a los config e incrementas los números a valores no usados: ej dos BD apuntan a 3306 una la incrementas a 3307 siempre que 3307 no esté siendo usado por otra BD en ese caso sube a 3308 etc.